# SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH with Multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I got a workbook that in sheet1 has several columns of information the first of which, column `A2:A50`, is a range of order#'s.

In sheet2 there is a column `C2:C45`, is a range of orde#'s.
I am using the following formula to detect if one of the orders in sheet1 has matched to the orders in sheet2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$45sheet2,A2sheet1)))>0
```

It works great!
However, I would like to expand the formula, so once it has found a matched order then it looks into column `B1:B45` sheet2, which is a range cell content contains "processed" or "canceled".

FYI- The column B is across refernce to that matched order# which I'd like to extract either of text wording.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should the result be? Some sample data would be nice here too.

Comment: If SEARCH succeeded(True) then search for a text string and return multiple adjacent values. I.e.order# 1235(col.A sheet1) Text Value(col.B sheet2) Processed or Cancelled order# item 1235(col.C sheet2) order#4569(col.A sheet1) Text Value(col.B sheet2) Processed item 4569(Col.B sheet2). I'd like to get either Processed or Cancelled from column B in sheet2. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the sample data, instead of adding in a comment? Or maybe add a screenshot? Does VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH not work?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I can't add attachments, I'm new to this site and I've very limited permissions. Unfortunately, the VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH won't work. The main reason is that the second lookup cell contains both text and numbers(order #'s). Something like this.. gthyruy19767543.tester  The best option is the SUMPRODUCT (ISNUMBER (SEARCH. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a link to the screenshot - either in the question or in a comment - and someone will take care of editing it for you.